# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::num_rows() in (...) line 36

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, login-control

Here my first question . I'm a newbie in PHP and CI but i want to learn :)

First my model :

> class Login_model extends MY_Model {
>
> ```
> protected $table   = 'users';
> protected $primary = 'user_id';
>
> function __construct()
> {
>
>     parent::__construct();
> }
>
> public function validate()
> {
>     // Récupère le POST du login
>     $user_mail = $this->input->post('user_mail');
>     $password  = sha1($this->input->post('user_mail') . $this->input->post('password'));
>
>     //Execution de la requete
>
>     $query = $this->users_m->get(array('user_mail' => $user_mail));
>     // Verification qu'il existe un enregistrement
>     var_dump($query);
>     if($query->num_rows() == 1)
>     {
>         // If there is a user, then create session data
>         $row = $query->row();
>         $data = array(
>                 'userid' => $row->userid,
>                 'fname' => $row->fname,
>                 'lname' => $row->lname,
>                 'username' => $row->username,
>                 'validated' => true
>                 );
>             $this->session->set_userdata($data);
>             return true;
>             //      }
>             // Si le login ne se valide pas
>             // return false.
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This model extends My_model MY_MODEL.PHP

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * MY_Model
 */
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{

  /**
   * Connexion à la BDD
   * 
   * @var object 
   */
  protected $link;

  /**
   * Groupe de connexion BDD
   * 
   * @var string 
   */
  protected $db_group = 'default';

  /**
   * Table de la BDD
   * 
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = '';

  /**
   * Clé(s) primaire(s)
   * 
   * @var string/array
   */
  protected $primary = 'id';

  /**
   * Déclanche une exception
   * 
   * @var boolean
   */
  private $_throw_exception = TRUE;

  /**
   * Constructeur
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    if ($this->table != '')
    {
      $this->_set_link();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Connexion à la BDD
   */
  private function _set_link()
  {
    $this->link = $this->load->database($this->db_group, TRUE);
  }

  /**
   * Active la gestion des exceptions
   */
  public function enable_exception()
  {
    $this->_throw_exception = TRUE;
  }

  /**
   * Desactive la gestion des exceptions
   */
  public function disable_exception()
  {
    $this->_throw_exception = FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * Récupère un enregistrement unique
   * 
   * @param array $where
   * @return boolean
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public function get($where = array())
  {
    if (is_array($where) && $where)
    {
      foreach ($where as $key => $value)
      {
        $this->link->where($key, $value);
      }
    }

    $query = $this->link->get($this->table);

    /* Traitement de la requete */
    $data = FALSE;

    if (is_object($query))
    {
      if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
      {
        $result = $query->result();
        $data = $result[0];
      }
      else if ($this->_throw_exception)
      {
        throw new Exception($query->num_rows(), 11);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception($this->link->_error_number() . ":" . $this->link->_error_message(), 10);
    }
    return $data;
  }

  /**
   * Liste des enregistrements de la table
   * 
   * @param array $orders
   * @return array
   */
  public function get_all($where = array(), $orders = array(), $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL)
  {
    /* Conditions */
    if (is_array($where) && $where)
    {
      foreach ($where as $key => $value)
      {
        $this->link->where($key, $value);
      }
    }

    /* Tris */
    if (is_array($orders) && $orders)
    {
      foreach ($orders as $order)
      {
        $this->link->order_by("$this->table.$order");
      }
    }
    else if ($orders)
    {
      $this->link->order_by("$this->table.$orders");
    }
    else if (is_array($this->primary))
    {
      foreach ($this->primary as $order)
      {
        $this->link->order_by("$this->table.$order");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $this->link->order_by("$this->table.$this->primary");
    }

    /* Requete */
    $query = $this->link->get($this->table, $limit, $offset);

    /* Traitement de la requete */
    $data = array();

    if (is_object($query))
    {
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
        $data = $query->result();
      }
    }
    else if ($this->_throw_exception)
    {
      throw new Exception($this->link->_error_number() . ":" . $this->link->_error_message(), 10);
    }

    /* Retour */
    return $data;
  }

  /**
   * Nombre d'enregistrements de la table
   * 
   * @return integer
   */
  public function count($where = array())
  {
    if (is_array($where) && $where)
    {
      foreach ($where as $key => $value)
      {
        $this->link->where($key, $value);
      }
    }

    $this->link->from($this->table);

    return $this->link->count_all_results();
  }

  /**
   * Insertion dans la BDD
   * 
   * @param array $data
   * @return boolean
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public function insert($data = array())
  {
    $insert = FALSE;
    if ($this->link->insert($this->table, $data))
    {
      if (is_array($this->primary))
      {
        $insert = TRUE;
      }
      else if (isset($data[$this->primary]))
      {
        $insert = $data[$this->primary];
      }
      else
      {
        $insert = $this->link->insert_id();
      }
    }
    else if ($this->_throw_exception)
    {
      throw new Exception($this->link->_error_number() . ":" . $this->link->_error_message(), 20);
    }
    return $insert;
  }

  /**
   * Insertion de masse dans une base de donnée
   * 
   * @param array $data
   * @return boolean
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public function insert_batch($data)
  {
    $insert = FALSE;

    if ($this->link->insert_batch($this->table, $data))
    {
      $insert = TRUE;
    }
    else if ($this->_throw_exception)
    {
      throw new Exception($this->link->_error_number() . ":" . $this->link->_error_message(), 20);
    }

    return $insert;
  }

  /**
   * Mise à jour d'enregistrements de la BDD
   * 
   * @param array $data
   * @param array $where
   * @return boolean
   * @throws ExceptionModel
   */
  public function update($data = array(), $where = array())
  {
    $update = FALSE;

    if (is_array($where) && $where)
    {
      foreach ($where as $key => $value)
      {
        $this->link->where($key, $value);
      }
    }

    if ($this->link->update($this->table, $data))
    {
      $update = TRUE;
    }
    else if ($this->_throw_exception)
    {
      throw new Exception($this->link->_error_number() . ":" . $this->link->_error_message(), 30);
    }

    return $update;
  }

  /**
   * Suppression d'enregistrements de la BDD
   * 
   * @param array $where
   * @return boolean
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public function delete($where = array())
  {
    $delete = FALSE;

    if (is_array($where) && $where)
    {
      foreach ($where as $key => $value)
      {
        $this->link->where($key, $value);
      }
    }

    if ($this->link->delete($this->table))
    {
      $delete = TRUE;
    }
    else if ($this->_throw_exception)
    {
      throw new Exception($this->link->_error_number() . ":" . $this->link->_error_message(), 40);
    }

    return $delete;
  }

}

/* End of file MY_Model.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Model.php */
```

I have my controller : Accueil ( will be the default route )

The method login() call the view login.php

ACCUEIL.PHP :

```
    <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Accueil extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('users_model', 'users_m');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('template');
    }

    public function index($msg = NULL) //msg en cas d'erreur , NULL si pas d'erreur
    {
        $data['msg'] = $msg;
        $this->load->view('/login', $data);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        // Chargement du model de login
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        // Validation que l'user puisse se connecter
        $result = $this->login_model->validate();
        // Verification du résultat
        if (!$result)
        {
            // Pas de validation on renvoit vers l'index
            $msg = '<font color=red>Nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect(s).</font><br />';
            $this->index($msg);
        }
        else
        {
            // Si validation ok,
            // On l'envoit vers la partie "protégée"
            redirect('home');
        }
    }

}
```

Finally the view : LOGIN.PHP

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>connexion</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="kliklipse">

        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo css_url('bootstrap.min'); ?>">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
            }

            .form-signin {
                max-width: 300px;
                padding: 19px 29px 29px;
                margin: 0 auto 20px;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            }
            .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
            .form-signin .checkbox {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .form-signin input[type="text"],
            .form-signin input[type="password"] {
                font-size: 16px;
                height: auto;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                padding: 7px 9px;
            }

        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo css_url('bootstrap-responsive.min'); ?>"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo css_url('main'); ?>">  


        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">



            <form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo base_url();?>accueil/login" method="post" name="process">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Identifiez vous</h2>
                <br />
                <?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?> 
                <input type="text" name="user_mail" id="user_mail" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Adresse Email">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Mot de passe">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Se souvenir de moi
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Se connecter</button>
            </form>

        </div> <!-- /container -->

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container-narrow">
                <p>&copy; Kliklipse 2013 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Gestion des utilisateur & groupes</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="<?php echo js_url('bootstrap.min'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo js_url('sorttable'); ?>"></script>
        <script>var base_url = <?php echo base_url(); ?></script>

        <!-- {elapsed_time} seconds-->
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the error with num_rows() that its a undefined method... just dont know why..

If any questions, ask me ( and sorry for my english ^^)

Comment: It is not a function of database class ? 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html
maybe i did something wrong to use it ?

Comment: I ask myself something...
Login_model extends My_Model.
My_Model extends CI_Model.
and Num_rows() is a method of CI_Model... 
Is this the reason ? How can i fix it ?

Comment: My apologies. CodeIgniter uses the name method name as the mysqli num_rows() method in PHP. I was looking for your database connection object. In that case, all I can think of is checking to see if $query has successfully connected to your database or not.

Comment: I think it is successfully connected cause the var_dump($query) answer is : 

object(stdClass)#24 (4) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "21" ["user_name"]=> string(9) "kliklipse" ["user_password"]=> string(40) "8cf9050d638ea7f2593b87f560c9531a21a85b82" ["user_mail"]=> string(21) "cedric.duma@gmail.com" }

Comment: Try declaring your $query property outside of your methods at the top of your Login_model class, and then use $this->query to access it throughout your code. I think it may be a scope issue when you're trying to access $query elsewhere in your classes.

Comment: tbh I think it's because you're trying to redeclare CI's get in your MyModel. You have public function get in there which would effectively overwrite the CI standard get, then you call it from itself. Rename your MyModel get to something else and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`num_rows()` is to be used only with CI's database object resource (not results). And this `$query = $this->users_m->get(array('user_mail' => $user_mail));` doesn't look like it.

Try something like this:

`$query = $this->db->get_where('table_name', array('user_mail' => $user_mail));`

Then you can use `$query->num_rows();`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question which call to `num_rows()` is causing the error. But I'm going to assume it is from your Login Model, the line right after the `var_dump($query);`

In your your `My_model` `get` function you have the following:

```
if (is_object($query))
{
  if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
  {
    $result = $query->result();
    $data = $result[0];             <<<<<< NOTE THIS
  }
  else if ($this->_throw_exception)
  {
    throw new Exception($query->num_rows(), 11);
  }
}
```

and you return `$data` from `get`.

At this point `$data` is a `$CI_result` object, which doesn't have the `num_rows()` method available, that's a method from the query class.

[CI results docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

If you are checking in `My_model` for num rows, you don't need to do it in your Login Model. You can call the methods directly now, as you've done the checking already.

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the error.

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
```

is not the correct syntax

```
if ($query->num_rows == 1)
```

is the correct one. $query->num_rows  value is "1"

finally the solution i choose is :

my user_model.php (for database operation with users )

```
class Users_model extends MY_Model
{

    protected $table   = 'users';
    protected $primary = 'user_id';

    public function liste()
    {

        $this->link->select('user_id');
        $this->link->select('user_name');
        $this->link->select('user_mail');
        $this->link->select("GROUP_CONCAT(group_name ORDER BY group_name SEPARATOR '<br />') AS user_groups", FALSE);

        $this->link->join('groups_users', 'users_user_id=user_id', 'left');
        $this->link->join('groups', 'group_id=groups_group_id', 'left');

        $this->link->group_by('user_id');

        return parent::get_all(array(), array('user_name ASC'));
    }

    public function validate($mail, $password)
    {
        $pass_hashed = sha1($mail . $password);
        return parent::get(array('user_mail'     => $mail, 'user_password' => $pass_hashed));
    }

}
/* End of file users_model.php */

/* Location: ./application/models/users_model.php */
```

The validate method is more simple, and i dont do any controls in it. Just Db operations.

Now my controller accueil.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Accueil extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('users_model', 'users_m');        // Chargement model
        $this->load->library('form_validation');             // Librairie validation
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));           // helpers
        $this->load->library('template');                   // Librairie template
    }

    public function index($msg = NULL) //msg en cas d'erreur , NULL si pas d'erreur
    {
        $data['msg'] = $msg;
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }

public function login()
    {

        try
        {
            $user = $this->users_m->validate($this->input->post('user_mail'), $this->input->post('password'));

            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'user_id'   => $user->user_id,
                'user_mail' => $user->user_mail,
                'validated' => TRUE
            ));

            redirect('users');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // Pas de validation on renvoit vers l'index avec un message d'erreur
            $msg = '<font color=red>Nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect(s).</font><br />';
            $this->index($msg);
        }
    }

}

/* End of file accueil.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/accueil.php */
```

My view is still the same , no changes.

I think i have wrote the code more correctly this time.

Separate the DB operations , with the controls.

Feel free to comments.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this happens if  the following statement is missing 
(ie . the url helper is not yet loaded manually or automatically)
`$this->load->helper('url');`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
num_row()
```

by this:

```
if(!empty($Variable))
...............
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's too hard to solve use:

```
$count($query);
```

instead

```
$query->num_rows();
```

:/